# Firebase Cloud Function Firestore Transaction TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to update and delete using transaction in Firebase Cloud Function.

But getting an error like this:

[image]

**My Code:**

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp();
 const firestore = admin.firestore();

 exports.updateUserSize = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
var userDocRef = firestore.collection("users").where('uid', '==', user.uid).limit(1);

return firestore.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    return transaction.get(userDocRef).then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(userDoc => {
            if (!userDoc.exists) {
                throw "userDoc does not exist!";
            }
            console.log("user_uid: " + userDoc.data().uid + " | instanceDocId: " + userDoc.data().instance);

            var instanceDocRef = firestore.collection("utils").doc(userDoc.data().instance);
            return transaction.get(instanceDocRef).then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach(instanceDoc => {
                    var newUserSize = instanceDoc.data().user_size - 1;
                    transaction.update(instanceDoc, { user_size: newUserSize });
                });
            });
        });
    });    

}).then(function() {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: my code here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA4Md.jpg

Comment: Please add your code **as text** in your question. It will be easier to copy/paste in order to try it and to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try your Cloud Function but the problem most probably comes from the fact that with

```
var instanceDocRef = firestore.collection("utils").doc(userDoc.data().instance);
return transaction.get(instanceDocRef).then((snapshot) => {})
```

you get a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) and not a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) as you get with

```
var userDocRef = firestore.collection("users").where('uid', '==', user.uid).limit(1);
...
return transaction.get(userDocRef).then((snapshot) => {
```

A `DocumentSnapshot` does not have a `forEach()` method. You have to do as follows, directly calling the `data()` method of the `DocumentSnapshot`:

```
var instanceDocRef = firestore.collection("utils").doc(userDoc.data().instance);
return transaction.get(instanceDocRef).then((snapshot) => {
    var newUserSize = snapshot.data().user_size - 1;
    ...
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. solved but I got a new problem.
Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.

My Code:

                var instanceDocRef = firestore.collection("utils").doc(userDoc.data().instance);
                return transaction.get(instanceDocRef).then((snapshot) => {
                    console.log("snapshotn: " + snapshot.data().user_size);
                    var newUserSize = snapshot.data().user_size - 1;
                    transaction.update(instanceDocRef, { user_size: newUserSize });
                });

Comment: link of my new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843093/firebase-firestore-transaction-error-cannot-modify-a-writebatch-that-has-been-c

hopefully you can help me again, thank you