# Firebase Firestore Transaction Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed

Tags: javascript, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am deploying on cloud functions, and getting this error

```
Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.
at WriteBatch.verifyNotCommitted (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:112:19)
at WriteBatch.update (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:299:14)
at Transaction.update (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/transaction.js:225:33)
at transaction.get.then (/user_code/index.js:22:40)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Below is my code, I am using transaction to update and delete on Firestore.

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp();
   const firestore = admin.firestore();

  exports.updateUserSize = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
var userDocRef = firestore.collection("users").where('uid', '==', 
 user.uid).limit(1);

return firestore.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    return transaction.get(userDocRef).then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(userDoc => {
            if (!userDoc.exists) {
                throw "userDoc does not exist!";
            }
            console.log("user_uid: " + userDoc.data().uid + " | instanceDocId: " + userDoc.data().instance);

            var instanceDocRef = firestore.collection("utils").doc(userDoc.data().instance);
            return transaction.get(instanceDocRef).then((snapshot) => {
                console.log("snapshotn: " + snapshot.data().user_size);
                var newUserSize = snapshot.data().user_size - 1;
                transaction.update(instanceDocRef, { user_size: newUserSize });
            });
        });
    });    

}).then(function() {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
 });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the ENTIRE code of your Cloud Function. It is important for the persons that try to help you to see all the code. Thanks. Also, can you indicate which line is #22?

Comment: I think your problem comes form the fact that you are returning several times the `transaction` into the `forEach` loop. Also you don't return the transaction when doing `transaction.update(instanceDocRef, { user_size: newUserSize });`.

Comment: line #22: transaction.update(instanceDocRef, { user_size: newUserSize });, can you give an example for update's return?

Comment: I would kindly suggest that you study into detail the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction. With the `forEach` loop I think that you are not following the constraint: "A transaction consists of any number of get() operations **followed** by any number of write operations such as set(), update(), or delete(). "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using a for loop, as mentioned by @Renaud Tarnec in the comments.

> I think your problem comes form the fact that you are returning several times the `transaction` into the `forEach` loop. Also you don't return the transaction when doing `transaction.update(instanceDocRef, { user_size: newUserSize });`. I would kindly suggest that you study into detail the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction. With the `forEach` loop I think that you are not following the constraint: "A transaction consists of any number of get() operations **followed** by any number of write operations such as set(), update(), or delete(). "